# How to find better algorithm for my prefix matcher algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was solving online problem and the task was something like this:

> There are two arrays: *numbers* and *prefixes*.
>
> - Array `numbers` contains numbers: “+432112345”, “+9990”, “+4450505”
> - Array `prefixes` contains prefixes: “+4321”, “+43211”, “+7700”, “+4452”, “+4”
>
> Find longest prefix for each number. If no prefix found for number, match with empty string.
>
> For example:
>
> - “+432112345” matches with the longest prefix “+43211” (not +4321, cause 43211 is longer).
> - “+9990” doesn't match with anything, so empty string "".
> - “+4450505” matches with “+4”  (“+4452” doesn’t match because of the 2).

I came up with the most straight forward solution where I loop through each number with each prefix. So each time new number, I check prefixes, if some prefix is longer than last one, I will change.

```java
Map<String, String> numsAndPrefixes = new HashMap<>();

for (String number : A) {
    for (String prefix : B) {
        if (number.contains(prefix)) {
            // if map already contains this number, check for prefixes. 
            // if longer exists, switch longer one
            if (numsAndPrefixes.containsKey(number)) {
                int prefixLength = prefix.length();
                int currentLen = numsAndPrefixes.get(number).length();
                if (prefixLength > currentLen) {
                    numsAndPrefixes.put(number, prefix);
                }
            } else {
                numsAndPrefixes.put(number, prefix);
            }
        } else if (!number.contains(prefix) && !numsAndPrefixes.containsKey(number)){
            numsAndPrefixes.put(number, "");
        }
    }
}
```

So it will have two for loops. I see that each time I am doing the same job over and over, e.g checking for prefixes. It works, but it is slow.  The problem is that I can’t come up with anything better.

Could someone explain how they would approach to find better algorithm?

And more general, how do you proceed if you have somewhat working solution and trying to find better one? What knowledge am I still missing?

Comment: you can use Trie or Suffix tree data structures for more optimal solution, still it depends on time limit and stuff like that, if your solution works fast enough for your purpose those data structures are overkill.

Comment: You do realize that `number.contains(prefix)` is `O(max_prefix.length)` and you do that check for `numbers.length*prefix.length` times, your actual complexity ends up with `O(n*p*max_prefix.length)` where `n` is number of `number`s and `p` is number of `prefix`es.

Comment: No, I did not realize that. Thanks for poining that out. Will check ```contains()``` function.

Comment: Actually `contains` is `O(max_number.length)`

Comment: Jetty solved the same problem for URL path mappings -> https://webtide.com/jetty-9-goes-fast-with-mechanical-sympathy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement this using a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and the [`floor(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor-E-) method.

```
String[] numbers = { "+432112345", "+9990", "+4450505" };
String[] prefixes = { "+4321", "+43211", "+7700", "+4452", "+4" };

TreeSet<String> prefixSet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(prefixes));
for (String number : numbers) {
    String prefix = prefixSet.floor(number);
    while (prefix != null && ! number.startsWith(prefix))
        prefix = prefixSet.floor(prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1));
    if (prefix == null)
        prefix = "";
    System.out.println(number + " -> " + prefix);
}
```

*Output*

```
+432112345 -> +43211
+9990 -> 
+4450505 -> +4
```

Comment: This is nice, but I can't see how come is your solution faster than mine. You are still looping each number with prefixes which I see is still O(n**2)? No? 
And can you please explain how expensive is to put array to TreeSet? Is it ok to do when some other data structure is somehow better?

Comment: @AverageJoe9000 Your code is a full Cartesian join of `numbers` and `prefixes`, so _O(n*m)_. This solution is _O(n*log m)_. On average, it probably only has to look up in the `prefixSet` about 3 times per phone number, not scan the full `prefix` array. Sure, there is a one-time _O(m*log m)_ startup cost to build the `Set`, so if you only have a few numbers or prefixes, it may not be worth it, but if the prefix list is huge, which it will be if you're doing all the international prefixes, and you have a lot of phone numbers to check, then the performance gain is immense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you briefly describe how do you approach this kind of solution? I'm trying to figure out where do I lack some knowledge.

Comment: @AverageJoe9000 Difficult to say. Learn about the capabilities of the various Java API classes. You don't have to remember the details, just high-level capabilities, e.g. in this case the capability to find neighboring values, which is a feature of both `TreeMap` and `TreeSet`, as well as sorted arrays where you can use `Arrays.binarySearch()` to find the location in sorted array. So at a very high level, finding neighboring values can be done for sorted collections.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you need is [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

- Add all prefixes in trie
- For each string `S` in `numbers`:

  - Start from the root of trie
  - For each character in `S`:

    - If there is a link from current node, associated with current character, go by this link to the next node
    - If there is no link, then you reached the longest prefix - prefix stored in the current node is the answer for `S`

This algorithm works in `O(length(prefixes) + length(numbers))`

Comment: I would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.contains()`. You should use `.startsWith()`. It's **a lot** faster.

Then in your `else if` you are checking what you already checked in the `if`.

This is only **one approach** on how to improve the algorithm:

Sort the prefixes:

+43211 +4321 +4452 +4 +7700

What is good about this? Well, it will always find the longest prefix first. You can exit the loop and don't have to look for longer prefixes.

```
Arrays.sort(prefixes, new Comparator<String>() {
@Override
public int compare​(String o1, String o2) {
    return o1.startsWith(o2) ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
}
});

Map<String, String> numsAndPrefixes = new HashMap<>();

for (String number: numbers) {
    numsAndPrefixes.put(number, "");
    for (String prefix: prefixes) {
        if (number.startsWith(prefix, 1)) {
            numsAndPrefixes.put(number, prefix);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But if your number starts with +1 and there is no prefix it will continue checking all the prefixes with `+2 +3 +4` ... which are obviously not matching. (Issue 1)

Also if your number starts with `+9` the prefix will be found very late. (Issue 2)

How to fix this? Well you can save the indices where +1 starts, +2 starts, ...:

In our prefix list:

```
0      1     2     3  4  5   (index)
+1233  +123  +2233 +2 +3 +4
```

+2 starts at index [2] and +3 starts at index [4]. So when you want to know the prefix for a number starting with +2 you only have to check elements [2] and [3]. This will both fix issue 1 and 2.

It would also be possible to store the indices for more digits (for example where +13 starts).